# Stack Overflow Careers' fonts look bad in Chrome

Tags: support, jobs, fonts

When browsing the Stack Overlflow Careers site, the fonts look really bad in Chrome, while they look good in IE9. The zoom level in Chrome is 100%. Other Stack Exchange sites look good, it's just the Careers site. Running on Windows 7.

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think that's just how Chrome renders fonts.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? Also, since other sites display fine, I assume you have ClearType enabled?

Comment: No-repro. Looks fine to me on 20.0.1132.57

Comment: Looks fine on OS X.

Comment: I can't see any difference myself (IE9 and Chrome 20 on Win7 x64).

Comment: Looks fine on Arch.

Comment: The browser probably just needs more hipster

Comment: ClearType is disabled in the Chrome screenshot.  http://superuser.com/questions/308135/how-can-i-improve-font-appearance-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't repro this -- the http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ homepage looks fine to me in Chrome (current ver) on Windows 7

Font list is

> font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif

**I suspect you have Helv Neue installed.** I've heard it can render badly on Windows, and Chrome in particular has not adopted the newer Firefox 4.0+ and IE9+ font rendering strategies on Windows...

Comment: It looks slightly different (better) on my PC with Helvetica Neue installed, but the premise remains the same - Helvetica and its variants are known to look bad on Windows.

Comment: This is correct - it only reproduces on a Windows machine that has Helvetica Neue installed. I tested on two machines with Neue and one without - looked consistently bad in the first two cases, and no issue in the later case.

Comment: how can I overcome this problem? Fonts render just fine on SO and meta, but on rest of SE they look awful and causes eye fatigue. On SO & meta font:`Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif` but on other sites `Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`. Edit: windows 7, happens on chrome, FF, IE.

Comment: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/J4dqHZD3dcs This solved it once and for all.